# UILabel returns "nil"?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel, null, ibaction

I am having trouble with my UIButton. For Example, when I click the the UIButton `Number3` and hit the `checkButton` on the ViewController the result in the `currentCountLabel` is Optional(3). It does this for every number after I click the `checkButton`. If I then click the button again, the `currentCountLabel` says, "nil". Here is all of my code:

ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var currentCountLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

var currentCount: Int = 0

var IncorrectLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

var CorrectLabel: UILabel = UILabel()

var currectAmountCorrect : Int = 0

var currentAmountIncorrect : Int = 0

var flashTimer : NSTimer = NSTimer()

var timerCounter : Int = 0

var randomImageGeneratorNumber : Int = 0

var flashingImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView()

var flashButton: UIButton = UIButton()

var currentTime = NSTimer()

func timerFunc() {
    flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden
    flashingImageView.hidden = !flashingImageView.hidden
}

@IBAction func flashButton(sender: UIButton) {

    flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden
    flashingImageView.hidden = !flashingImageView.hidden
    flashingImageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image\(arc4random_uniform(6) + 1).png")

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image1")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 1

    }

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image2")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 2

    }

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image3")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 3

    }

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image4")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 4

    }

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image5")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 5

    }

    if (flashingImageView.image == UIImage(named: "Image6")){

        randomImageGeneratorNumber == 6

    }

    currentCount = 0
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"

    if (flashButton.hidden == true){
        flashButton.hidden = true;
        flashingImageView.hidden = false
    }

    var currentTime = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: "timerFunc", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    func timerFunc(){
        self.flashingImageView.hidden = true;
        flashButton.hidden = !flashButton.hidden
        flashingImageView.hidden = !flashingImageView.hidden
    }

}

@IBAction func checkButton(sender: UIButton) {


    if (flashButton.hidden == true){
        flashButton.hidden == false
        flashingImageView.hidden == true
    }

    var currentCount = currentCountLabel.text?.toInt()
    if randomImageGeneratorNumber == currentCount {
        currectAmountCorrect += 1
        CorrectLabel.text = "\(currectAmountCorrect)"

    } else {
        currentAmountIncorrect += 1
        IncorrectLabel.text = "\(currentAmountIncorrect)"
    }

    if (currentCountLabel.text == "0"){

        let alert = UIAlertView()
        alert.title = "Alert"
        alert.message = "You must type in an answer in order to check it"
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Understood")
        alert.show()

}
     currentCount == 0
     currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}


@IBAction func clearButton(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = 0
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}


@IBAction func Number1Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 1
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}

@IBAction func Number2Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 2
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}

@IBAction func Number3Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 3
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}

@IBAction func Number4Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 4
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}

@IBAction func Number5Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 5
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}

@IBAction func Number6Button(sender: UIButton) {
    currentCount = currentCount * 10
    currentCount = currentCount + 6
    currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var currentCountLabel = "\(currentCount)"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
}
```

I have no idea what so ever is happening or how to fix it.

Any input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you clarified how you want it to behave. If you're wondering why it's an optional and why it's returning `nil` then you can fix this as follows.

In your `checkButton()` function you have this line at the end:

```
currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount)"
```

Unwrap the `currentCount` variable to this:

```
currentCountLabel.text = "\(currentCount!)"
```

Within this same `checkButton()` function you have this line:

```
currentCount == 0
```

So if you're wondering why it's not returning `0` it's because you're using a comparison operator not an assignment operator.

Comment: … and the reason it’s returning nil is because (in `var currentCount = currentCountLabel.text?.toInt()`), the `toInt` method returns an `Optional<Int>`, not an `Int`. If the string in `currentCountLabel.text` were “Sarah”, it wouldn’t parse to an integer at all, and would return `nil`.